# Help in self-studying mathematics.

Tags: soft-question, learning

Is this a reasonable list for who seek to learn mathematics by "self learning" program?
and is it a well sorted list to follow?
http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/index/index.html

Comment: It depends on what you mean when you say "learn mathematics". What mathematics are you interested in? What is your actual level?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learning mathematics as if an absolute beginner?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22513/learning-mathematics-as-if-an-absolute-beginner)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Our very own Pete Clark, now of the University of Georgia faculty, was once upon a time a very talented undergraduate student at the University of Chicago. Back then, he and several of his fellow U of C honor students compiled a list of their recommended textbooks at various levels and posted it online. It does need to be updated, but I think you'll find it quite helpful. In fact,I've been asking Pete to revise it for a few months now. I hope he'll eventually find the time to do so.

Here it is:

http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~abhishek/chicmath.htm

Comment: The person who originated the Chicago mathematics bibliography, Chris Jeris, has contacted me to tell me that he is trying to revive it.  I don't have the details on hand at the moment, but probably an internet search will suffice.

Comment: @Pate Thanks for the heads up-I just might drop your old classmate an email asking him if he'd like me to contribute.

Comment: thank you can guys for help, i appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

Dave Rusin's web site contains many interesting nuggets of information, but it is not, and is not meant to be, a coherent course of study.

Answer (score 3):

The list you provided is quite concise. Notice however that a reasonable load of classes would be something like 4 per semester so with a 4 year program, you will cover around 32 of the list at best (unless you skip around). That's why you should just cover basic core classes first (real analysis, complex analysis, algebra, ODE/PDE, etc).

[MIT Open Courseware](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/) will have a broad range of lists that include topics you listed and you can find lists of courses by going to any university mathematics program website and looking at the curriculum requirements (which will usually have a suggested program).

Comment: i am looking for a chronological list of mathematics topics to follow as a guide. if you can take a look at the link provided and tell me if it's a good list to abide by.

Comment: I must disagree Khan Academy is a good resource.

Comment: Pardon, I read the question incorrectly.

Comment: Honestly, google searches for lecture notes tend to be much more useful than the notes at MIT Courseware. They do have nice video lectures though.