# Tips for an adult to learn math -- from the beginning.

Tags: soft-question, learning

First let me start with I am an adult and I can't do simple maths. I some how got through all of my math courses in University (after *several* attempts) but I honestly couldn't tell you how...

I cannot do these:

- Add/Subtract with decimals
- Add/Subtract fractions
- Basic multiplication
- Basic division
- More advanced math that uses these principles

How can I go about learning these things now? Is there a particular book that I can study from (with worksheets). I'd really rather not do exercises that involve connecting dots to create pictures, or coloring things...

As a side note, I believe I suffer from [dyscalculia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyscalculia#Symptoms).

Comment: Out of interest, what course did you take at university?

Comment: Linear Algebra (I/II), Discrete Mathematics, Statistical Methods

Comment: That's interesting!!

Comment: @6005 Would you please refrain from bumping this many years-old questions at once for the sake of a tag-edit? This pushes legitimate recent questions off the homepage.

Comment: @Lord_Farin My apologies. I'm trying to work towards the removal of the [tag:self-learning] tag, but I have only been doing it very occasionally, and in blocks of only 10-15 questions at a time.

Comment: @6005 That sounds reasonable. The only advice I'd like to add is to monitor the homepage to make sure you don't exceed ~40% of the first view. One way I have done this in the past is by editing other questions on the homepage to improve their formatting or things like that, so they get bumped over your tag edits.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Thanks for the tip, I'll try that sometime.

Comment: @6005: Why don't you contact the maintainers of MSE and ask them to replace one tag by the other (assuming you have a solid justification for this)? It would take them only a few seconds.

Comment: @ 에이바 Apart from the of arithmetic content, ambiance plays some part I think.Open ventilated  places, working mornings after a good night sleep, and a bit of no-side effect natural homeopathic medication etc. would also help.

Comment: @AlexM. See [my question on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/smart-automatic-mass-retagging).

Comment: **Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/22513**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the following four playlist in order. These are made for people who don’t know how to add or subtract and it even explains the decimal number system.

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL301908982CBFE20D&feature=plcp 
http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL50D1D09ABE9CE271&feature=plcp
 http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1C68557896CFABA8&feature=plcp
 http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE23E2FDF6E935778&feature=plcp

I hope this helped. It helped me to learn other stuff. Of course you can start from a more advanced playlist if you feel you already know one of them.

Comment: Ah, The Khan Academy! I can't believe I didn't think to look there. Thank you. I will go through these.

Comment: Working through the exercises on the Khan academy knowledge map is a fun way to practice.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking Blocks is a great resource for understanding ratios and proportions.(And it also has addition and subtraction.  It's very interactive. It guides you one step at a time, and gives you feedback every step, so you know if your thinking is correct.  You don't have to wait until the end of the problem to find out.