# How to learn mathematics as a beginner

Tags: soft-question, advice

I am a 15 year old mobile app developer. I had a tough time understanding maths when i was little, which have thrown me off balance when i try to study maths or attend a maths class. Things don't actually sink in, i do well in my maths exam because my teachers just want us to cramm(rote learn) some formulas and procedures and upload them during exams. I feel that there is alot to maths than just cramming stuff. Sorry for the whole introduction of me, but i just wrote it so that your answer would be more tailored to my situation.
 I would be going into game development soon i know it would require alot of maths and i just developed this urge to learn maths right from the beginning to a great level with 6 months or a year. My problem is WHERE TO START and KEEP GOING more like a curriculum, but i want to start like a beginner with zero knowledge of maths so i would be able to get what i missed. I have searched google and seen answers on this site, but all of them have different resources and order, which makes me confused. All i need is what i should start learning first (and ebooks or resources) then what i should learn next and next so that everything flows and i can be a great mathematician.

Comment: I think you'll get downvotes for an opinion-based question.  Aside from that, for game development I would focus on game theory, trigonometry/geometry, and a little bit of calculus.  All three of these are areas where you can "keep going" your entire lifetime and never learn all there is to know.

Comment: Maybe you should give a better sketch of you abilities. "Zero" is not really a good explanation. I guess you will have some basic knowledge and the question is where does this knowledge end.

Comment: I closed my browse and i didn't login and my session was destroyed. So i can only communicate with the answer question. I know little of trigonometry, indices, logarithm, geometry (plane shapes), statistics. I said zero knowledge, because i want to start like a beginner, i want to empty my cup so i can be refilled. Do you mind recommending any ebook or website i can start with first ?.

Comment: @ElvisChidera: It might be possible to have your accounts _merged_.  Please follow (as best as you can) the directions given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: @ElvisChidera Your question is probably appropriate for the nearly-in-beta-SE http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64216/mathematics-learning-studying-and-education. 

Check out the proposal and commit to it if you're interested. Then we can get it off the ground and get the site in beta!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learning mathematics as if an absolute beginner?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22513/learning-mathematics-as-if-an-absolute-beginner)

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend you to use a site called  [Khanacademy](https://www.khanacademy.org/). I am 13 years old and I know Trigonometry, Calculus, Linear Algebra etc. all because of that website, it has a lot of educational videos on all topics from basic addition to differential equations.

Comment: I don't entirely agree with the philosophy inherent in khanacademy, but until you have some curiosity and some tools to chase it, it's not a bad solution.

Answer (score 3):

The key is motivation and practice...you will never be good at maths until you want to learn about it and want to do it.

Many people go on to do degrees in maths yet have no liking or actual understanding of it. It really isn't everyone's cup of tea to be honest!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. there are more than cramming stuffs in math. I think you want to clarify where you are at in the curriculum of the mathematics, right?

The most efficient way to find what you are missing is to solve as many problems as possible. On solving problems, you might know what you are missing on the curriculum!