# Book recommendation and online learning resources for mathematics as a hobby.

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

The career and field of study I am choosing is not related to maths much.But I am still interested and I love maths.But I just know math up to highschool level.So I wish to learn more,say as a hobby or skill.

Thus what books can anyone recommend or online resources or even what branch of mathematics to learn .

Edit:I know there are some answers pertaining to this but they dont seem like what I wanted to ask.

Comment: The pacing...${}$.

Comment: I've been a big fan of http://www.cut-the-knot.org/ and of Ross Honsberger's books. On a more advanced level, combinatorics texts such as Stanley's undergraduate ones or Bona's or Loehr's.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Okay thats something I will look into.

Comment: Self learning is good but unless you have real drive and/or talent I would recommend a formal education in mathematics up to the second year of college, if possible. This would include all of Calculus including multi-variable calculus as well as Linear Algebra and Differential Equations. These are generally considered the requisite courses for any of the sciences, engineering or economics disciplines.

Comment: @JohnDouma Sorry for the late reply , I had a question .Suppose I do an Economics Degree, will I learn the branches you mentioned as an integral part of the course or separately?

Comment: It depends upon your school and its program. Economic theory uses a lot of mathematics. Some undergraduate programs will stress mathematics more than others. If you go on to graduate school you will need even more math than I mentioned above. The first two years will give you a foundation that will let you begin to study more advanced mathematics. That's why I recommend those courses even if it is only a hobby.

Comment: @JohnDouma Okay thanks for that.I was considering doing an economics course.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learning mathematics as if an absolute beginner?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22513/learning-mathematics-as-if-an-absolute-beginner)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Khan academy might be a good starting point.

On youtube you can watch hundreds of their
short videos on subjects like 
algebra, calculus, probability, linear algebra etc.

When you feel like you master that material
you can move on to MIT OpenCourseWare on youtube.

Gilbert Strang's Linear algebra.

David Jerison's Single variable calculus.

Denis Auroux's Multivariable calculus.

Tom Leighton's Mathematics for Computer Science.

They also have courses on probability, statistics,
differential equations etc.

Other personal favourites, which i actually liked more than MIT, are these

[Discrete Mathematics. Arsdigita University. Instructor: Shai Simonson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_9WjWENWV8&list=PL3o9D4Dl2FJ9q0_gtFXPh_H4POI5dK0yG)

[The Fourier Transforms and its Applications. Standford. Professor Brad Osgood](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZNm7L96pfY&list=PLB24BC7956EE040CD)

[Probability. Harvard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbB0FjPg0mw&list=PL2SOU6wwxB0uwwH80KTQ6ht66KWxbzTIo)

[Probability Primer. Mathematicalmonk's channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tk4ubu7BlSk&list=PL17567A1A3F5DB5E4)

[General topology from the very basics, including set theory, techniques for proofs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivO9_O0YSSc&list=PLpG_ISEhQ6z0Q5MaIvdn5tBJFWfp9fZtQ)

[Graph theory by Sarada Herke](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIb1cz06UwI&list=PLoJC20gNfC2gmT_5WgwYwGMvgCjYVsIQg)