# Learn mathematics

Tags: self-learning

At school, I was very good at mathematics, but now I'm 40 years old and I think I have forgotten almost everything I have learnt. I want to study again mathematics because I'm very interested on it.

How can I learn it? Is there any book or encyclopedia to learn it (calculus and algebra)?

I don't want to learn on school's books because I'm sure I'm going to get bored with them.

What are your recommendations?

Comment: There are many topics in mathematics. Only learning calculus and algebra is not enough in my opinion.

Comment: You should try Khan Academy...

Comment: The web has a wealth of lecture notes on algebra and analysis. Just try what you find interesting.

Comment: @McCheng I want to learn as much as possible. I remember that at school I learnt calculus and algebra.

Comment: At which level have you stopped your studies ? It is only an indication but it can help to give more appropriate advices.

Comment: Learning abstract algebra is a great way to start developing mathematical abilities such as proof-writing and general manipulations as I see it.

Comment: @JeanMarie At University. I'm a computer engineer.

Comment: If you really want to learn mathematics, I think you may begin by reading books on philosophy of mathematics.

Comment: @user170039 I disagree with this 100%. In fact learning philosophy will be detrimental to learning math.

Comment: My favourite for begginers is **Challenge And Thrill of Pre-College Mathematics**. It has lucid and clear guidance. But it's written by Indian writers. Don't know if it's available outside India or not.....

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: "In fact learning philosophy will be detrimental to learning math." - really? Why?

Comment: I am 36 and a while ago i was in sort of the same situation as  you. You can look at my answer here [Book recommendations and online learning resources for mathematics as a hobby](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1768011/book-recommendation-and-online-learning-resources-for-mathematics-as-a-hobby/1768834#1768834)

Comment: There are many textbooks written by mathematicians that are not boring.

Comment: Using an "encyclopedia"  to learn mathematics sounds boring.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learning mathematics as if an absolute beginner?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22513/learning-mathematics-as-if-an-absolute-beginner)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question, I wish you the best of luck. Here is a different suggestion, of course its just that, another idea. Dont start with algebra/calculus its so standard and tied up with school/university curricula. Instead learn some different areas of mathematics that dont require background and are more conceptual. Good examples are Combinatorics, including graph theory, very beautiful ideas here, requiring no background, but youll be solving propblems and learning yo think mathematically. Other possibilities are Set theory, Logic, Euclidian Geometry, Projective Geometry and of course elementary number theory.

Comment: I agree with @Rene Schipperus for Combinatorics. I wouldn't say the same for set theory ! I would advise you, because algebra is central wathever you do to use a **computer algebra system** (Mathematica, Maple...) in order to gain confidence by being able to check permanently your computations and not find his pass obstructed by lengthy calculations.

Comment: @JeanMarie I disagree with this 100%. One needs to develop intuition about computations and not become dependent on Wolfram Alpha like so many other people on this site. Second, its abstract concepts that are the most important.

Comment: I think the most difficult part in mathematics is that it has its own language and a lot of abstract concepts.

Comment: @VansFannel: That's why I think that it is worthy to study this language in great depth. Philosophy of mathematics may be a good start from this point of view.

Comment: @VansFannel Yeah, thats very true but its essential to learn these things. But the most powerful mathematics is always the most abstract, in some sense mathematics is about abstraction. You learn to love it, and the interplay between the abstract and the concrete is beautiful.

Comment: @user170039 What are you working for the philosophy department ? You want to learn the language of Math not that of Philosophy, they are two TOTALLY different things. Besides philosophy has its head so far up its....

Comment: @Rene Schipperus I surely will not enter into polemics. I agree of course that maths can in no way be assimilated to algebraic computations (even if we spend a large part of our time computing in diverse ways...), and I do not consider Wolfram Alpha as being ... the Alpha and Omega. I just wanted to say that for somebody as VansFannel who is a Computer Engineer who has stopped doing computations, he has to re-inforce his past capabilities without practising ; computer algebra systems, especialy Mathematica, can be very helpful, because you can practise on it even in abstract sectors (ctd.).

Comment: (ctd) have you seen , it is only one example, but as we where speaking about Combinatorics, the so powerful library called  "Combinatorica" in Mathematica ?

Comment: "You want to learn the language of Math not that of Philosophy, they are two TOTALLY different things." - I don't understand this. Can you explain the reason(s) for this TOTAL distinction?

Comment: @JeanMarie Again I simply disagree, its funny, they guy says he wants to study math and one person tells him he should learn philosophy and another computer science...I recommend he also learns German, French and Russian...first! then with any luck he will never get down to math. (And "surely" who uses the word "surely"?)

Comment: I will think about learning French... :)

Comment: If anyone can find anything of substance in Wittgenstein's book "Philosophy And Mathematics" I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: Regarding Wittgenstein's philosophy of mathematics you may read [this](http://www.iep.utm.edu/wittmath) and [this](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein-mathematics/).

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Many philosophy students have idols that they cannot let go off. That is often why they keep telling others to worship the same idols. In fact, that is one of the major reasons why "learning philosophy will be detrimental to learning math", because most of it is about parroting idols. The other reason is that most philosophers are completely incompetent in basic logic. For example, Wittgenstein spouted nonsense when he couldn't understand Godel, but till today all his idolizers repeatedly try to find new-fangled ways of twisting all his words in an attempt to save face.

Comment: Of course some students of other subjects also have idols, but when a subject has more substance there is naturally less reliance on "thus spake idol XXX".

Comment: @user21820  . When the geometer Coxeter was at Oxford and Wittgenstein was a Visiting Professor there, W. asked C. what he thought of his new book. (I d.k. which book that was.) C. replied that he thought it was gibberish.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Thanks for sharing that; I didn't know about Coxeter's opinion. It's kind of ironic that philosophy (φιλοσοφια) is supposed to be grounded in the love of knowledge. Feel free to find me [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51337/this-is-the-realm-of-simply-beautiful-art) if you or Rene would like to talk more about this. =)

Answer (score 2):

Introduction To Geometry by Donald Coxeter. Great fun, doesn't need to be read linearly. No pre-requisites. If you thought there wasn't much to geometry in 2 dimensions..... For calculus, if you don't have a clear grasp of the logical foundations of the real number system, you will be lost. Perhaps someone else can recommend some modern texts that cover this.

Answer (score 2):

As someone who naturally gravitates towards self-study (even in the formal classroom setting), the first thing you MUST understand is that you are in for a grueling (but ultimately very satisfying) marathon and NOT a sprint, no matter where you start. My experience is that self-study (well, really all learning) is not suited for the linear dogma of the educational orthodoxy. Understanding comes in waves and often has a way of eluding the rigid schedules of classroom based education. Even when I first took calculus, I *understood* very little of it until about two weeks after the course was over. At first, the mind is so overwhelmed by the minutae of a new intellectual endeavor that one cannot see the forest for the trees but once one has become comfortable with the language/notation/main results of a given field the insight tends to come in waves and often when one least expects it.

Be warned that you have to be incredibly stubborn and disciplined to self-study mathematics. It takes a certain measure of ruthlessness towards oneself to make meaningful progress. I would also recommend investing in MuPad or Mathematica but not so you can avoid computation (it is a necessary evil) but so that you can ensure that your computation is correct. It is also fun to play around with and I cannot overstate the value of "playing around" with ideas. This site is also a valuable resource with a great many sharp minds who truly love mathematics and will gladly assist you so long as you put forth the necessary effort.

As for where to start, I recommend linear algebra followed by calculus/analysis but you would probably be advised to brush up on your basic algebra (it comes back faster than you'd expect). If it were me, I'd stray away from the more esoteric fields that some have suggested and build up a solid foundation. Linear Algebra Done Right by Sheldon Axler is a quality text, though you might consider supplementing it with a more computationally based text like Strang to get the hang of the basic operations, especially if it your first time around the block.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are searching for (english only):
https://www.thegreatcoursesplus.com/category/mathematics

I'm with you on this, text books can be really boring especially with the medial opportunities of today. (Think of ads and the CSI series, why can't a math class be like this :( )

The great courses offers video courses on demand thought by the best teachers they can find and good medial explanation work.

Tipp: Register for the newsletter and wait a week you will get far superior offers