# Resources for learning Mathematics for new devotee

Tags: online-resources

After a random encounter with Mathematics, I was astounded to discover that it finally began to click. With this new finding, I decided to get myself a beginner's book to brush up on my math skills. I opted for 'Basic Mathematics' by Serge Lang that I quickly devoured, I really loved doing the exercises and finally understanding them. I honestly cannot fathom how I missed on this magnificent discipline, this is why I come to you for suggestions for new resources to tackle! I lean more on the side of application than theory, thank you!

Comment: https://realnotcomplex.com/

Comment: Thanks, Don for this amazing website!

Comment: Some of the books [listed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4204998/13130) might be of interest.